# How to kick off R file with command line

Tags: r

I am on a windows machine and want to run a file called main.r so in the command line I put:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\r.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\R Projects\soultion\MAIN.R"
```

when I run this nothing happens. The command line just goes to the next line.

Can you advise what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is what is supposed to happen.  Output gets piped to MAIN.Rout in your case.  If you want the output to display in the terminal use Rscript instead of R CMD BATCH.